# In vue 3 (vite), how to replace index.html to folder src

Tags: vue.js

I have a project on vue 3 (vite). I want the file to index.html it was in the src folder. How to do it?

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import * as path from 'path';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint';

export default defineConfig({
 root: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
 plugins: [vue(), eslintPlugin()],
 resolve: {
  alias: [
   { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') },
   { find: '@@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets') },
  ],
},
});
```

Error: Pre-transform error: Failed to load url /src/main.js (resolved id: /src/main.js). Does the file exist? (x2)

Comment: The question is hard to understand.  I'm guessing index.html has been moved inside the src directory and you're getting an error from index.html that it can't find main.js?  If so, it's because you've configured vite's root as `src` so now `/src/main.js` leads to `/src/src/main.js`.  In your index.html you need to remove `/src` from the path, e.g. `<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>`